# Interpretation of main effects when interaction is present in gam

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

Consider a GAM model with the following structure:
`y~gam(s(x1, by=x2) + x2 + s(x3))` where `x1` and `x2` are continuous variables and `x2` is categorical.  If I want to know the effect of `x1` (in terms of deviance explained), I remove `x1` from the model and compare the deviance explained ([following this thread](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Re-variance-explained-by-each-predictor-in-GAM-td896222.html)), like this:

```
model1 <- y~gam(s(x1, by=x2) + x2 + s(x3)) 
model2 <- y~gam(x2 + s(x3))
## deviance explained by x1:
summary(model1)$dev.expl-summary(model2)$dev.expl
```

But what if I want to know the effect of `x2`?  I am not interested in the effect of `x2` on `x1`; I just want to know the effect of `x2` by itself.  Could I do this:

```
model3 <- y~gam(s(x1, by=x2) + s(x3)) 
## deviance explained by x2:
summary(model1)$dev.expl-summary(model3)$dev.expl
```

I know that for linear models, if a significant interaction is present, one cannot remove the main effects of the variables in that interaction, even if they are not significant.  Does the same apply here, in that I cannot know the effect of `x2` on `y` independently of its effect on `x1`?

Comment: First sentence should be where x1 and x3 are continuous variables and x2 is categorical.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same apply here. Whenever there are any interactions involving a variable, you cannot make any affirmation over the effects of this variable.

However, notice that this type of effect you are retrieving from explained deviance, doesn't have the same interpretability as the usual in linear models, where you affirm that a modification of a single unit in x2 represents an increase of beta2 over the mean of y. In fact, they are two different effects. Hence, by removing, only the x2 parameter you can still say that you have an explained deviance increase that is interpretable. The only difference is that the interpretation is in terms of information loss, or uncertainty decrease, which is absolutely fine to do.